# How i can return value from some form to many forms

Tags: c#-4.0

I have three forms, Form1 orders, Form2 deliveries, Form3 customers.
Form1 call to Form3 when looking for a customer and returns the customer to Form1.
Form2 call to Form3 when looking for a customer and returns the customer to Form2.
How I do it dynamically?
Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways of doing this.

Create a property FoundCustomer in Form3 and set the value to relevant object if found and to null if not found. Once you return from Form3 to parent form you use this property to get the name.

You can achieve the same using events as well.

Look at [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14122/Passing-Data-Between-Forms) for more details.